# Overriding the add method for ArrayList<Integer>

Tags: java

Question: I am trying to override the add method of ArrayList to remember the last three digits added to the arraylist. I am to then take these three values and find the maximum value among them.

It seems that I can not get my add method to save the three elements without an out of bounds error.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MaxThreeArrayList extends ArrayList<Integer> {

    MaxThreeArrayList maxlist = new MaxThreeArrayList(); 

    int third_last = 0;
    int second_last = 0;
    int last = 0;

        @Override public boolean add(Integer o){
            if (maxlist.size() == 1){
                last = maxlist.get(maxlist.size() - 1);
            }
            else if (maxlist.size() == 2){
                last = maxlist.get(maxlist.size() - 1);
                second_last =  maxlist.get(maxlist.size() - 2);

            }
            else if (maxlist.size() >= 3){
                last = maxlist.get(maxlist.size() - 1);
                second_last =  maxlist.get(maxlist.size() - 2);
                third_last =  maxlist.get(maxlist.size() - 3);
            }

            return super.add(o);
        }

        public int getMax(){
           int maximum = 0;
           if (third_last >= second_last){
              if (third_last >= last){
                  maximum = third_last;
              }
           }
           if (second_last >= third_last){
              if (second_last >= last){
                  maximum = second_last;
              }
           }
           if (last >= second_last){
              if (last >= third_last){
                  maximum = last;
              }
           }
           return maximum; 
         }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

}
```

Comment: You can easily do this with an additional circular array or even a stack; you're probably over-complicating it.

Comment: You can also get the maximum with `Collections.max(subList(size() - 3, size()))`

Comment: You are not adding anything to the 'maxlist'

Comment: You probably shouldn't have a `MaxThreeArrayList` instance being created in the constructor of the same class, as that will immediately create a recursive call which overflows the stack. You can use `this` or `super` to reference the `ArrayList` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should separate your concerns. Your overridden `add` should only worry about remembering the last three things you add to the list. This can be accomplished pretty easy with a deque. The method `getMax` should figure out which one is the largest, as its name suggests.

```
public class MaxThreeArrayList extends ArrayList<Integer> {
    private final Deque<Integer> deque = new LinkedList<>();

    @Override public boolean add(Integer i) {
        deque.addFirst(i);
        if (deque.size() > 3) { deque.removeLast(); }
        return super.add(i);
    }

    public Integer getMax() {
        Integer max = 0;
        for (Integer i : deque) {
            if (i > max) { max = i; }
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

As an additional exercise, you may note that this code can be made more general. It doesn't need to be hard-coded to remember the last 3. You could make that number configurable.